# Correct font sizes when LTR and RTL mixed

Tags: css

I have issues with font sizes when they are a mix of LTR and RTL contents. Say, I have text like this:

```
<p>في 12 ساعة</p>
```

It will be easy if I can place span with direction LRT to correct the font sizes, such as:

```
<p>في <span dir="ltr">12</span> ساعة</p>
```

But they are many and mixed, so placing a span is not possible inside some body text or titles.

As you see 12 is LTR. The rest are RTL.

My CSS defines:

```
p{font-size:16px;}
```

This looks good for RTL, but too big for LTR(here, 12).

What I want:
- keep font-size to 16px for RTL
- make its LTR font-size 12px

Do you think there is a CSS property to scan automatically the direction without placing span tag for each LTR?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot "scan" the text with CSS.
Try using a font that's not so small in Arabic. A 4px difference is too much if you ask me. I usually add 1px or 2px max for Arabic text.
Try "Tahoma"(it's relatively big in Arabic text)

Comment: Thanks, Tahoma looks rasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this example for you
all text has 12px, but any text inside the p > span will have bigger text
Now of course you can add class to the span 
in this case your css will change to
http://jsfiddle.net/9uVD8/1/

p > span.className {....}